# How to create a message app filter extension for iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a message filter app extension.  I searched about it and got to know about identity lookup which is newly introduced concept in ios 11.0. I came to know that I have to insert keys in info.plist

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
       <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
            <string>MessageFilterExtension</string>
       <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
       <key>ILMessageFilterExtensionNetworkURL</key>
       <string>https://www.example-sms-filter-application.com/api</string>
     </dict>
       <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
       <string>com.apple.identitylookup.message-filter</string>
     </dict>
```

But after inserting these, When in build app, I am getting black screen. I have just inserted this code only. nothing else in view controller.swift file and made a file MessageFilterExtension.swift with same class name.

**This is the documentation:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/identitylookup/creating_a_message_filter_app_extension

Comment: Hi please tell where i am wrong in  posting this question.

Comment: I am guessing, but this may have been downvoted for (1) being too broad or lacking reproducibility, (2) not being clear as to where you are stuck, (3) offering a link for people to read without giving a reason why people would wish to read it, (4) adding repeated please-help-me begging into the question body. I have not voted myself.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@lucianboboc/creating-a-message-filter-extension-580c9957633d), to create an extension all you have to do is create a new iOS app and from the Xcode menu select File/New/Target and select Message Filter Extension.

In your extension a class that inherits from `ILMessageFilterExtension` is automatically created for you. It also conforms to the `ILMessageFilterQueryHandling` protocol which has a single requirement, the `handle(_ queryRequest:context:completion:)` method.

In this method a query request object of type `ILMessageFilterQueryRequest` is passed to you and you will have access to the sender and `messageBody` of the message.

After you apply your filter rules, you need to call the completion closure which will take a single parameter of type `ILMessageFilterQueryResponse` that you need to create and set it’s action property.

If you want to prevent the message from being shown you need to set the action type to `.filter`. The other 2 options `.none` and `.allow` will have no effect, the message will be shown normally.

That’s all you have to do to create a Message Filter Extension.

Below is an example from the Filter [Spam SMS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filtersms/id1254903440?mt=8) app that uses a CoreData shared container to load the list of keywords created by the user, which are used to filter the message body:

```
import IdentityLookup

final class MessageFilterExtension: ILMessageFilterExtension {
var words:[Item] = []
let stack = CoreDataStack()

func loadItems() {
    let context = stack.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let itemDAO = ItemDAO(managedObjectContext: context)
    let allItems = itemDAO.fetchItmes()
    self.words = allItems.flatMap({ item in
        return item.value != nil ? item : nil
    })
 }
}

extension MessageFilterExtension: ILMessageFilterQueryHandling {

func handle(_ queryRequest: ILMessageFilterQueryRequest, context: ILMessageFilterExtensionContext, completion: @escaping (ILMessageFilterQueryResponse) -> Void) {

    let action = self.offlineAction(for: queryRequest)
    let response = ILMessageFilterQueryResponse()
    response.action = action
    completion(response)
}

private func offlineAction(for queryRequest: ILMessageFilterQueryRequest) -> ILMessageFilterAction {
    guard let messageBody = queryRequest.messageBody?.lowercased() else { return .none }

    self.loadItems()

    for word in self.words {
        if let value = word.value,
            messageBody.contains(value.lowercased()) {
            return .filter
        }
    }
    return .allow
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Hasan! Do you happen to know what is the correct way to debug this extensions? Do I need to send my self messages basically?

Comment: Hey Hasan, Is there any extra code needed to create an app setting under "Phone Setting -> Messages -> Unknown and Spam -> App Name"?  It's mandatory to turn on this setting to filter incoming SMS.